# Advanced PHP: error in soapclient

Tags: php

I am getting following error while accessing methods from strimics system in "soapclient"

```
Fatal error: 
Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Unauthorized in C:\wamp\www\studiofathom\test.php:25  
Stack trace: 
#0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'https://fathomc...', 'tempuri....', 1, 0) 
#1 C:\wamp\www\studiofathom\test.php(25): SoapClient->__soapCall('CreateCustomer', Array) 
#2 {main} thrown in C:\wamp\www\studiofathom\test.php on line 25
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried any other actions on this soap-server? Does it require authentication? As far as I know, you're simply not authenticated to use it (or this method)...

Comment: i did one test example to simply connect soap server and it is working fine

Comment: i can get all methods and types using __getMethods() and __getTypes() methods but if i call any of particular method it fives error

Comment: It can be that you are authorized to connect to the soap, and view it's methods and types, but not perform any other calls. Depending on the implementation of the soap server. In our soap server it works the same, we have a 'per method' user authorisation system.

Comment: I think best thing to do is contact the owner of the soap server to check and adjust your authorization levels.